# Stuck in the bulk data transfer in mysql workbench data transfer while migrating the data from access to mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ms-access-2010, database-migration, bulkinsert

I m transferring the database from the Microsoft Access database to MySQL workbench. All the steps goes well but at the last step in Transfering the bulk data i got stuck in the erorr.

Error =  Determine number of rows to copy: Error getting row count from source tables, wbcopytables exited with code 3221225477
Failed.

Here we have the error log:

```
Starting...
Prepare information for data copy...
Prepare information for data copy done
Determine number of rows to copy....
Counting number of rows in tables...
wbcopytables.exe --count-only --passwords-from-stdin --odbc-source="DSN=eastern_backend" --source-rdbms-type=MsAccess --source-timeout= --target-timeout=None --table-file=C:\Users\hatim\AppData\Local\Temp\tmputmjo05c
--table     "tblShippingMethods"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblUsers"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezr_Report Groups"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblPayments"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblCalendar"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezy_GroupPermissions"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblErrors"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblErrorLog"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblReturns"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblInvoiceStatus"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblAdjustments"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblInvDetailsWithInv#"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezy_Users"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblCreditCard"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "eza_Preferences"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezr_Report List"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblReportList"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblShippers"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblItems"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblEmployeeTitles"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezr_Report Definitions1"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblInvoiceDetails"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblProductCategory"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblBillOfLading"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezr_Report Definitions"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblPODetails"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezy_Permissions"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblCustomers"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tbl_Dates"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezr_Report List1"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblSupplierType"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezy_GroupUser"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblReceipts"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblSuppliers"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblPOMaster"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblTerritory"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezy_AuditLog"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblEmployees"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblCompany"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblInvoices"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezr_Report Print Queue"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "ezy_Groups"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblBillOfLadingDetails"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblRelations"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblProducts"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblStates"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: --table    "tblPalletType"
21:45:33 [INF][      copytable]: Opening ODBC connection to [MsAccess] 'DSN=eastern_backend;PWD=XXX'
21:45:34 [INF][      copytable]: ODBC connection to 'DSN=eastern_backend;PWD=' opened

Loading table information from file C:\Users\hatim\AppData\Local\Temp\tmputmjo05c
ROW_COUNT::"tblShippingMethods": 3
ROW_COUNT::"tblUsers": 21
ROW_COUNT::"ezr_Report Groups": 1
ROW_COUNT::"tblPayments": 122296
ROW_COUNT::"tblCalendar": 242
ROW_COUNT::"ezy_GroupPermissions": 43
ROW_COUNT::"tblErrors": 1
ROW_COUNT::"tblErrorLog": 5822
ROW_COUNT::"tblReturns": 4
ROW_COUNT::"tblInvoiceStatus": 2
ROW_COUNT::"tblAdjustments": 1
ROW_COUNT::"tblInvDetailsWithInv#": 529790
ROW_COUNT::"ezy_Users": 1
ROW_COUNT::"tblCreditCard": 4
ROW_COUNT::"eza_Preferences": 4
ROW_COUNT::"ezr_Report List": 31
ROW_COUNT::"tblReportList": 13
ROW_COUNT::"tblShippers": 2
ROW_COUNT::"tblItems": 2
ROW_COUNT::"tblEmployeeTitles": 1
ROW_COUNT::"ezr_Report Definitions1": 1
ROW_COUNT::"tblInvoiceDetails": 2106567
ROW_COUNT::"tblProductCategory": 1
ROW_COUNT::"tblBillOfLading": 1
ROW_COUNT::"ezr_Report Definitions": 3
ROW_COUNT::"tblPODetails": 2
ROW_COUNT::"ezy_Permissions": 72
ROW_COUNT::"tblCustomers": 5203
ROW_COUNT::"tbl_Dates": 4353
ROW_COUNT::"ezr_Report List1": 31
ROW_COUNT::"tblSupplierType": 2
ROW_COUNT::"ezy_GroupUser": 1
ROW_COUNT::"tblReceipts": 5
ROW_COUNT::"tblSuppliers": 699
ROW_COUNT::"tblPOMaster": 2
ROW_COUNT::"tblTerritory": 13
ROW_COUNT::"ezy_AuditLog": 4
ROW_COUNT::"tblEmployees": 61
ROW_COUNT::"tblCompany": 1
ROW_COUNT::"tblInvoices": 140831
ROW_COUNT::"ezr_Report Print Queue": 246
ROW_COUNT::"ezy_Groups": 3
ROW_COUNT::"tblBillOfLadingDetails": 1
ROW_COUNT::"tblRelations": 12
ROW_COUNT::"tblProducts": 2765
ROW_COUNT::"tblStates": 51
ROW_COUNT::"tblPalletType": 5
FINISHED

ERROR: Determine number of rows to copy: Error getting row count from source tables, wbcopytables exited with code 3221225477
Failed


Resuming...
Failed
```

Please help me how to get out from these or the other alternative of the data transffering from access database to MySQL database useing MySQL workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check once that your tables are connected in a proper manner or not,
eg: in my case in the parent table the unique id key was missing which was projecting the other table using the foreign key.
so I have checked and cleared the row in a table whose reference table does not have the same entry.
And it works for me.